# Importar dependencias de build gradle a pubspec.yaml y utilizarlas con Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, ios, dart

Soy desarrollador de Android hace masomenos 2 años con Android Studio, y ahora quería empezar con Flutter pero tengo una duda y necesito saber que hacer para poder construir una app.

Necesito hacer una app conectada vía Bluetooth a dispositivos médicos.

El equipo de trabajo me envió los links del sdk (Android e iOS)

Eh visto ejemplos de como agregar las dependencias tanto en Android como iOS dentro del proyecto de flutter.

Pero no sé cómo agregarlas luego al archivo pubspec.yaml.

No se me da mucho una idea de si es necesario que el Sdk también tenga una versión en dart o si flutter puede hacer una conversión del sdk de Android a dart para poder utilizarlo en Flutter.

Entonces, en resumen:

Tengo un sdk para trabajar en mis apps. Tengo los links para agregar en dependencias.

La pregunta es ¿Como los agrego al proyecto de flutter para trabajar el Sdk con dart ?

Los sdk que debo utilizar son los siguientes:

```
Import SDK

dependencies {
        ...
        implementation 'com.github.elinkthings:AILinkSDKRepositoryAndroid:Tag'//Bluetooth library(must)
        implementation 'com.github.elinkthings:AILinkSDKParsingLibraryAndroid:Tag'//Parsing library (including algorithms), need to rely on Bluetooth library(not required, it is recommended to rely on)
        implementation 'com.github.elinkthings:AILinkSDKOtaLibraryAndroid:Tag'//OTA library, need to rely on Bluetooth library(not necessary)
}
```

Las dependencias anteriores necesito incorporarlas a flutter para trabajarlas con Dart. Ese es mi problema.

Ayúdenme amigos! Estoy atascado!
Actualmente uso VSCode

Comment: necesitas usar platform channels, esas dependencias solo las podrás manejar dentro de código nativo (java/kotlin), de igual manera tendrás que hacer con iOS  ,  luego con platforms channels podrás intecambiar mensajes entre nativo y flutter

Comment: para tu problema puedes usar [platform-channels](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels)